# TextView not visible

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I write  the layout like following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:background="@drawable/history_unfiled_circle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It should be an icon in the left and two lines text in the right of the icon.
But the firstLine doesn't visible. I spent a lot time but can't solve it. Hope your help.

Update: In fact, I want to get this result
[image]

Comment: half of this xml looks like randomnly added without any reason. keep it simple!

Comment: @bofredo As what I have updated, this xml is attempted to get that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set your `RelativeLayout` `android:minHeight=?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight` and `android:layout_height=wrap_content`, since one of your text inside have fixed height.
2. Your `secondLine` `TextView` need to specify `android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"`

Answer (score 1):

This is how it looks like on my Android Studio with virtual device Nexus S.
[image]

And the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="80px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/black_mana_toggle"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you . But in my real phone, it appear like what I had said. And in fact, I need a TextView not ImageView here and I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are in a RelativeLayout. Change it to LinearLayout and don't forget to also add orientation. Read this document for clarification on when to use RelativeLayout and when to use LinearLayout.

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/

EDIT: also, if you fill_parent on your height (ImageView), your ImageView will dominate the whole screen.

Comment: As what I have updated, I want to get that result for each element of the ListView. And I don't think Linearlayout can get that more easily.Do you have any idea about that?Thank you